# Making a screencast software in java

Tags: java, awtrobot

This is how I plan to make it:
There will be a small JFrame with start and stop buttons to start and stop recording. Clicking start will start a thread that will create a `java.awt.Robot` that will take repeated screen shots.
Here is where my problem starts. Robot does take a screenshot but
1. The position of the cursor will not be recorded
2. I dont know where the image will be stored. I intend to store them in a folder whose name will be determined using `java.util.Date`.
3. I dont understand BufferedImage class one bit.

I have finished making JFrame and implemented the thread. I have package that I got from the internet that converts images to avi movies.
Please help me solve the above mentioned three problems.

**Edited:**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

public void captureScreen(String fileName) throws Exception {

   Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
   Rectangle screenRectangle = new Rectangle(screenSize);
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
   ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(fileName));

}
```

if you could please explain t he above mentioned code with respect to my problem.

Comment: And the question is? Do you want us to design and implement your application?

Comment: help with the image part. I have finished the directory creation, JFrame and rest. Apart from the image issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for getting the cursor in the screenshot is to:
figure out the position of the cursor.

```
java.awt.MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()
```

and place a rendered image of the cursor on top of the screenshot.
Take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html